# shiro configuration [urls] section dynamically

Tags: java, security, shiro

I am new to Shiro, I want to use this for securing my web application. I have tested it's various features.

I have also tested

```
[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout = logout
/admin/** = user, roles[admin]
/guest/** = user, roles[admin,guest]
```

But In my application I want to configure this section dynamically. I Found some solutions like dynamically create the Ini instance or implementation  but can they didn't solve my problem. Please provide me suggestion or way to out. 
Some code snippet will be better

Comment: Would this be dynamically (via code) during startup, or changeable throughout the whole application lifecycle?

Comment: Ya I wanted to do this or change as permissions for a particular URL changed by the user. Actually I was trying to configure shiro basic configuration using java-code, but I found that it gives preference to INI and get information from ini, I failed to configure without INI

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do this ?